# Не работает условие hack.А one_player и two_player работает хорошо

Tags: python, if, pygame

```
def main():
    if one_player or hack:
       if move == 'right' and player2.y > 0 and player2.rect.centery > ball.y:
         player2.y -= enemy_speed
       elif move == 'right' and player2.y < HEIGHT - player2.height and player2.rect.centery < ball.y:
         player2.y += enemy_speed

    elif hack:
       if move == 'left' and  player1.y > 0 and player1.rect.y > ball.y:
         player1.y -= enemy_speed
       elif move == 'left' and player1.y < HEIGHT - player1.height and player1.y < ball.y:
         player1.y += enemy_speed
def main_menu():
    global two_player
    global one_player
    global hack

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if red.collidepoint(mouse) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            one_player = True
            main()
        elif green.collidepoint(mouse) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            two_player = True
            main()
        elif purple.collidepoint(mouse) and pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
            hack = True
            main()
```